# Why do I get [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/srv/hiim/media/Bookshelf.png' in Django?

Tags: django, linux

So I have a Django application running on Ubuntu and nginx. I tried to let users upload photos, then ran into this error. (hiim is the name of my project, and Bookshelf.png is the image file I'm trying to upload)
I did some research, and noticed that I need to do `chmod` or `chown` command in order to solve this. so I did `sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu media`, because the problem was with the `media` directory. Then I did `ls -al` command, to see the ownership, and got this : 
`drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Jul 15 04:09 media` 
I thought the problem was solved but I keep getting the same error. What do you think is the problem? Thank you very much in advance. :)
+++ 
FYI, here are my relate codes. 
settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: did you try chmod with 777 (just for checking) ?

Comment: @mursalin Oh no I haven't. What does that command do? I've only tried ```chown```.

Comment: try ```chmod -R 777 media``` it would allow ```rwx``` for all user. ( its not a solution, you would not want to give all permission to all user. its for debugging reason only)

Comment: @mursalin Okay then what do I do after that command? FYI, my application is a CRUD application, where each user has his/her own diary, and I'm trying to enable them to attach some images :)

Comment: check if the error persists.

Comment: @mursalin Wow this works! Thank you so much. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217869/discussion-between-mursalin-and-ryan-oh).